# ¿Cómo convertir una fecha en texto?

Tags: sql-server

Buen día.

Lo que necesito es que por ejemplo  si tengo
10/06/2017

me lo convierta en `octubre seis de dos mil diecisiete` 
eso quiero hacerlo desde sqlserver en una consulta

Comment: "seis" como palabra?

Comment: Con ese formato si o sí debes caer en alguna rutina que convierta números a letras, si solo fueran los días sería más sencillo, pero al ser los años también, sin dudas lo primero es que te hagas una función como la que te comento, que reciba 6 y devuelva seis o 2017 y retorne dos mil diecisiete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tengo una funcion que me convierte los valores monetarios a letras, aún no se si es de mucha ayuda que lo pueda adaptar

```
public function numero_letras($num, $fem = false, $dec = true) {
        $matuni[2]  = "dos";
        $matuni[3]  = "tres";
        $matuni[4]  = "cuatro";
        $matuni[5]  = "cinco";
        $matuni[6]  = "seis";
        $matuni[7]  = "siete";
        $matuni[8]  = "ocho";
        $matuni[9]  = "nueve";
        $matuni[10] = "diez";
        $matuni[11] = "once";
        $matuni[12] = "doce";
        $matuni[13] = "trece";
        $matuni[14] = "catorce";
        $matuni[15] = "quince";
        $matuni[16] = "dieciseis";
        $matuni[17] = "diecisiete";
        $matuni[18] = "dieciocho";
        $matuni[19] = "diecinueve";
        $matuni[20] = "veinte";
        $matunisub[2] = "dos";
        $matunisub[3] = "tres";
        $matunisub[4] = "cuatro";
        $matunisub[5] = "quin";
        $matunisub[6] = "seis";
        $matunisub[7] = "sete";
        $matunisub[8] = "ocho";
        $matunisub[9] = "nove";
        $matdec[2] = "veinte";
        $matdec[3] = "treinta";
        $matdec[4] = "cuarenta";
        $matdec[5] = "cincuenta";
        $matdec[6] = "sesenta";
        $matdec[7] = "setenta";
        $matdec[8] = "ochenta";
        $matdec[9] = "noventa";
        $matsub[3]  = 'mill';
        $matsub[5]  = 'bill';
        $matsub[7]  = 'mill';
        $matsub[9]  = 'trill';
        $matsub[11] = 'mill';
        $matsub[13] = 'bill';
        $matsub[15] = 'mill';
        $matmil[4]  = 'millones';
        $matmil[6]  = 'billones';
        $matmil[7]  = 'de billones';
        $matmil[8]  = 'millones de billones';
        $matmil[10] = 'trillones';
        $matmil[11] = 'de trillones';
        $matmil[12] = 'millones de trillones';
        $matmil[13] = 'de trillones';
        $matmil[14] = 'billones de trillones';
        $matmil[15] = 'de billones de trillones';
        $matmil[16] = 'millones de billones de trillones';
        $float=explode('.',$num);
        $num=$float[0];
        $num = trim((string)@$num);
        if ($num[0] == '-') {
            $neg = 'menos ';
            $num = substr($num, 1);
        }else
            $neg = '';
        while ($num[0] == '0') $num = substr($num, 1);
        if ($num[0] < '1' or $num[0] > 9) $num = '0' . $num;
        $zeros = true;
        $punt = false;
        $ent = '';
        $fra = '';
        for ($c = 0; $c < strlen($num); $c++) {
            $n = $num[$c];
            if (! (strpos(".,'''", $n) === false)) {
                if ($punt) break;
                else{
                    $punt = true;
                    continue;
                }
            }elseif (! (strpos('0123456789', $n) === false)) {
                if ($punt) {
                    if ($n != '0') $zeros = false;
                        $fra .= $n;
                    }else
                        $ent .= $n;
                }else
                    break;
        }
        $ent = '     ' . $ent;
        if ($dec and $fra and ! $zeros) {
            $fin = ' coma';
            for ($n = 0; $n < strlen($fra); $n++) {
                if (($s = $fra[$n]) == '0')
                    $fin .= ' cero';
                elseif ($s == '1')
                    $fin .= $fem ? ' una' : ' un';
                else
                    $fin .= ' ' . $matuni[$s];
            }
        }else
            $fin = '';
        if ((int)$ent === 0) return 'Cero ' . $fin;
        $tex = '';
        $sub = 0;
        $mils = 0;
        $neutro = false;
        while ( ($num = substr($ent, -3)) != '   ') {
            $ent = substr($ent, 0, -3);
            if (++$sub < 3 and $fem) {
                $matuni[1] = 'una';
                $subcent = 'as';
            }else{
                $matuni[1] = $neutro ? 'un' : 'uno';
                $subcent = 'os';
            }
            $t = '';
            $n2 = substr($num, 1);
            if ($n2 == '00') {
            }elseif ($n2 < 21)
                $t = ' ' . $matuni[(int)$n2];
            elseif ($n2 < 30) {
                $n3 = $num[2];
                if ($n3 != 0) $t = 'i' . $matuni[$n3];
                $n2 = $num[1];
                $t = ' ' . $matdec[$n2] . $t;
            }else{
                $n3 = $num[2];
                if ($n3 != 0) $t = ' y ' . $matuni[$n3];
                $n2 = $num[1];
                $t = ' ' . $matdec[$n2] . $t;
            }
            $n = $num[0];
            if ($n == 1) {
                $t = ' ciento' . $t;
            }elseif ($n == 5){
                $t = ' ' . $matunisub[$n] . 'ient' . $subcent . $t;
            }elseif ($n != 0){
                $t = ' ' . $matunisub[$n] . 'cient' . $subcent . $t;
            }
            if ($sub == 1) {
            }elseif (! isset($matsub[$sub])) {
                if ($num == 1) {
                    $t = ' mil';
                }elseif ($num > 1){
                    $t .= ' mil';
                }
            }elseif ($num == 1) {
                $t .= ' ' . $matsub[$sub] . '?n';
            }elseif ($num > 1){
                $t .= ' ' . $matsub[$sub] . 'ones';
            }
            if ($num == '000') $mils ++;
            elseif ($mils != 0) {
                if (isset($matmil[$sub])) $t .= ' ' . $matmil[$sub];
                $mils = 0;
            }
            $neutro = true;
            $tex = $t . $tex;
        }
        $tex = $neg . substr($tex, 1) . $fin;
        $end_num = ucfirst($tex);
        return strtoupper($end_num);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Primer de la fecha, debes obtener el año, mes y día.

```
SELECT DAY(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), YEAR(GETDATE())
```

Después necesitas obtener el nombre del mes, así que para eso puedes usar el siguiente query:

```
SET LANGUAGE Spanish
DECLARE @mes INT
SET @mes = 1
SELECT DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, @mes-1, CAST('2008-01-01' AS datetime)))
```

Después de eso ocupas cambiar los números por letras. Para eso puedes revisar este [post](https://soportesql.wordpress.com/2014/06/26/conversion-de-numeros-a-letras-en-sql-server/) que con ciertas modificaciones te podría funcionar de lo mejor.

Answer (score 0):

**Posible solución (convertir fecha a formato largo)**

Imagínate que tienes el campo fec_actual en la tabla manzanas:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),manzanas.fec_actual,107) FROM manzanas
```

Comment: SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),GETDATE(),107) el problema si utilizo eso es que obtengo el resultado de oct 06, 2017

Comment: Acabo de ver tu edición, ahora cambia por completo lo deseado..., Se me ocurre un Replace para sustituir los números por lo deseado (Ej: 2 = dos).